# How to Hide/enable a Column in userControl when calling that control in other window?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a User control. It has Some textboxes. I need to hide a single column in that control and if require I need to set as visible. It's like, setting visibility property to a textbox visible/hidden/collapsed. Same thing I need to do in a Column for a user control.

Here is my code.

UserControl Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.UserControl"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">   
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
            <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />                      
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox Name="txt1"
                 Text="" 
                 Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/> 
        <TextBox Name="txt1"
                 Text="" 
                 Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        //....some othr controls..

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Window1.cs:

```
public partial class Window1
{
    public Window1()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         var uc = new UserControl();
         grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
         Grid.SetRow(uc, grid1.RowDefinitions.Count - 1);
         grid1.Children.Add(uc);         
    }
}
```

I need to hide the Column 1. How might I conceal this column and if require I need to Enable this column too. Any offer assistance??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column cannot be hidden by itself. Nevertheless you can wrap elements in column to one panel and then set its visibility to hidden/collapsed. You can also select all UIelements from column and subsequently set their visibility

```
var elements = Grid.Children.OfType<FrameworkElement>().Where(x => Grid.GetColumn(x) == ColumnNumber).ToList();
elements.ForEach(x => x.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed);
```

EDIT

I created Attached Properties for you problem. I have simple grid panel with 2 elements inside

```
<Grid local:MyGrid.IsHidden="True" local:MyGrid.ColumnNumber="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <TextBlock Text="2" Grid.Column="1" Name="tekst"/>
</Grid>
```

class MyGrid looks as follows:

```
public class MyGrid
{
    public static void SetIsHidden(DependencyObject obj, bool val)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsHiddenProperty, val);
    }

    public static bool GetIsHidden(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsHiddenProperty);
    }

    public static void SetColumnNumber(DependencyObject obj, int val)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ColumnNumberProperty, val);
    }

    public static int GetColumnNumber(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(ColumnNumberProperty);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsHiddenProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsHidden", typeof(bool), typeof(MyGrid));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnNumberProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ColumnNumber", typeof(int), typeof(MyGrid),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(-1, new PropertyChangedCallback((x, y) =>
        {
            if (x is Grid && GetIsHidden(x))
                ((Grid)x).Loaded += MyGrid_Loaded;
        })));

    static void MyGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (GetColumnNumber((DependencyObject)sender) >= 0 && GetColumnNumber((DependencyObject)sender) <= ((Grid)sender).ColumnDefinitions.Count - 1)
        {
            var elements = ((Grid)sender).Children.OfType<FrameworkElement>().Where(z => Grid.GetColumn(z) == GetColumnNumber((DependencyObject)sender)).ToList();
            elements.ForEach(s => s.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you set local:MyGrid.IsHidden to True and insert valid ColumnNumber local:MyGrid.ColumnNumber all UI elements will be hidden. 
Standard view
[image]

If you set

```
local:MyGrid.IsHidden="True" local:MyGrid.ColumnNumber="0"
```

[image]

For settings

```
local:MyGrid.IsHidden="False" local:MyGrid.ColumnNumber="0"
```

everyting stays normal
[image]

Comment: this code is hiding my entire usercontrol. i want to hide/collapse some particular column.

Comment: You must be doing sth wrong. I checked it and it worked. Did you add Name for grid like <Grid Name = "Grid">.

Comment: I appreciate your work buddy. Thanks for the help. Can i use Collapse property instead of Ishidden? Because it takes some space when its hiding. I dont want that.

Comment: Hidden means although is not visible it is placed on panel collapsed does not and automatically takes no place. If you don't mind mark this as answear and +1.

Comment: But i want collapse. I hope you understand what is collapse and Hidden. Anyhow i will look myself. Thanks once again:)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [`ColumnDefinition` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinition(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN, there is no `Visibility` property. Therefore, it is not possible to set the `Visibililty` of a `Grid.Column`. The customary way to do this would be to set the `Visibility` on each of the controls in that column.

The standard way to set the `Visibility` on one or more controls from other controls is to provide one or more `bool` properties:

```
public bool IsVisible { get; set; } // Implement INotifyPropertychanged interface here
```

Then we can data bind that property to the `Control.Visibillity` property of the relevant controls:

```
<TextBox Name="txt1" Text="" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Visibillity="{
    Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

You can use the same `Binding` on each of the controls in the column, so that they can all be hidden at once:

```
// Hide column controls
IsVisible = false;
// Show column controls
IsVisible = true;
```

Finally, if you create a `DependencyProperty` for the `IsVisible` property, then you would be able to data bind to it from outside of your `UserControl`:

```
<Local:YourUserControl IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleInMainWindowDataContext}" />
```

Then from object set as `MainWindow.DataContext`:

```
// Hide column controls
IsVisibleInMainWindowDataContext = false;
// Show column controls
IsVisibleInMainWindowDataContext = true;
```